# How to query in reactive mongo for like query for BigDecimal

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I am using ReactiveMongo, I want to create a query that performs like query with numbers (*BigDecimal*) in MongoDB. For eg: whole number like `4321.3456` should be matched by `4321.34`.

The following **2 queries** work on MongoShell to achieve this:

```
 db.employee.find({"$where":"/^4321.34.*/.test(this.salary)"})

 db.collection.find({ 
    "$where": function() { 
        return Math.round(this.salary * 100)/ 100 === 1.12; 
    }
})
```

But, I couldn't find a way to perform this query using ReactiveMongo.

How can I execute such queries using ReactiveMongo ?

**UPDATE**

I have tried following query

```
 val filter=Json.obj("$where" -> """/^4321.34.*/.test(this.salary)"""))
 collection.find(filter).cursor[JsObject]()
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @cchantep I have updated my question

Comment: @cchantep I have updated my question again

Comment: The [JSON extended syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) doesn't define a way to pass some JavaScript expression in such query. Using the BSON serialization, the [`BSONJavaScript`](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/api/index.html#reactivemongo.bson.BSONJavaScript) could be tried.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was sure that I will get only 2 digits after decimal part so I did range query like

```
val lowerLimit = 4321.34
val upperLimit = lowerLimit + 0.01
val filter = Json.obj("$gte" -> JsNumber(lowerLimit),"$lt" -> JsNumber(upperLimit))) 
collection.find(filter).cursor[JsObject]()
```

The above query works only if we are sure that only two digit after decimal part is sent. If three digits after decimal part is sent we have to do `val upperLimit = lowerLimit + 0.001`.